# Go to previous command without scrolling through multiline commands in iPython

Tags: ipython

I have the current newest version of iPython (7.6.1) and when I try to use the up-arrow keys to get to previous commands, when I hit a multiline command, the up-arrow instead slowly goes up through each line instead of going to the previous command. To get to the command before the multiline command, I have to scroll all the way up to the top of the multiline command before I can get to the previous command. Is there another shortcut I can use to skip the multiline command and get the previous one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At least on a Linux machine, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> appears to do the trick.

If search for a particular item, partial entry followed by up/dn is nice.  For example to find a previous function definition I might do

```
 def^p
```

The `?` help also suggests <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for a history search.  I haven't used that.

The `ipython shortcuts` section refers to me to `prompt_toolkit`, but that gives info on setting things up, not on current options.

---

In Macbook, you can use:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to go up
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to do down

Comment: I included the approach for Macbook. If you don't fell comfortable with me including it, just let me know and I will add as another answer

Comment: On a Mac with an external Windows keyboard, seems to be Shift + PgUp/Shift + PgDn.